# Updating an object by Reference (Suduko)

Tags: java, oop, object, pass-by-reference

I have a Sudoku puzzle solver that requires us to use recursion.. The problem is my boolean to check for available space is supposed to update the current position by reference and it is not. What would cause this?

```
    public boolean solve()
{
    Coordinate current = new Coordinate(); 

    if (findEmptyGridSlot(current)) {   // THE ERROR IS HERE **********  THIS IS SHOWING (0,0) STILL ******************

        for (int number = 1; number <= 9; number++)  
            if (canPlaceNumber(current, number)) { 
                grid[current.getRow()][current.getColumn()] = number; 

                if (solve()) 
                    return true; 

                grid[current.getRow()][current.getColumn()] = 0; 
            } return false;
    }else
        return true;

}

private boolean findEmptyGridSlot(Coordinate coordinate)
{
    boolean found = false;

    try{
        while (!found) 
        {
            if (grid[coordinate.getRow()][coordinate.getColumn()] == 0)
                found = true;
            else
                coordinate = coordinate.next(); // *****This is supposed to update the current coordinate ******
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        //CREATE No Empty Cells Exception
    } 
    return found;
}

public Coordinate next()
{
    Coordinate result = new Coordinate(row, column);

    result.column++;
    if (result.column > MAX_COORDINATE)
    {
        result.column = MIN_COORDINATE;
        result.row++;
        if (result.row > MAX_COORDINATE) result = null;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java passes by value. This means you are getting a *copy* of the reference to coordinate. If you point that copy to a new object (i.e. `coordinate = coordinate.next`) you are only changing the local copy. Now, on the other hand, if you changed an attribute of the object your variable refers to (e.g. `coordinate.x = foo` or `coordinate.setX(foo)`) that change will be visible to the caller of your method.

Answer (score 1):

jpm is correct, but I misread the first time so i'm going to try to clarity

```
private boolean findEmptyGridSlot(Coordinate coordinate)
```

A reference is passed by value. Think in these terms "coordinate" is a box that holds a piece of paper, on the piece of paper an address is written. coordinate is a box that belongs to only this method and it has its own piece of paper (many pieces of paper may have the same address written on them)

We can look in this box and 'post' things to the address written on the piece of paper, however when we say

```
coordinate=something
```

this means write on a new piece of paper the address of 'something'. Throw away the old piece of paper.

This action in no way affects the original 'house' that the first piece of paper had the address on. When my friend Jon updates his address book it doesn't matter what he writes, I still live in my house.

So, if coordinate has some easy substructure (eg x and y) you can 'post' an instruction to change x and y to be equal to the "next" one.

Or as a hack you can enclose a Coordinate inside annother object so you can post an instruction to it to change what the hack class points to

Test Code refered to in comments:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String bareMinObject="start";
        changeString(bareMinObject);
        System.out.println(bareMinObject); //Prints start, change string has no effect

    }

    public static void changeString(String input){
        String temp="end";
        input=temp;

    }

}
```

Comment: when you called findEmptyGridSlot(input) what this did was COPY the addres of input onto a new piece of paper and gave that piece of paper to findEmptyGridSlot

Comment: I created a temp variable and set it = to coordinate.next() then set coordinate = temp; and problem solved!

Comment: Are you completely sure that works? Because the way I read it it really shouldn't. See what I think is equivalent code in my main answer (so it formats properly).

Comment: Unless you mean you're doing it within the solve() method as opposed to the findEmptyGridSlot. As a general rule, using = in a method will only affect things within the method, using . may affect the underlying object.